# C++ Unit testing: Changing member scope

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for my class and would like to exercise methods that are private. I'm doing something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    Myclass() {}
    ~MyClass() {}
#ifdef TESTING
public:
#else
private:
#endif
    void MyMethod1();
    void MyMethod2();
};
```

If `TESTING` is defined, I change the class signature to make everything public. In my test code, I just do something like this:

```
#define TESTING
#include "MyClass.h"
void MyTestMethod()
{
    MyClass mc;
    mc.MyMethod1(); // Now I can access MyMethod1
}
```

So that its only public in my test files and not anywhere else. My testing executable sees a header that describes a class that is all public. The code for the class is actually being built somewhere else (where `TESTING` is not defined), so the scope will differ when the testing project links against the library.

Does this have the potential to break anything? I'm worried that this could change vtables locations or compiler and linker expectations if the header differs from what was actually produced in the object file.

Answer (score 5):

You risk ending up with low quality tests. Tests that are testing some implementation details not relevant to the actual function of the classes. Testing the public interface only drives you towards a good design and test cases that can stand code refactors without breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, although it's possible but don't do it that way instead create a wrapper class for your tests and use the `friend TestClass;` keyword in MyClass.

Comment: I thought of doing this, but then it makes it difficult to refactor code when you now have to change two method signatures instead of one. With the method I described, you have less changes and less classes to maintain.

Comment: What Martin pointed out is 100% true however if you still need to do this. You can create two versions of MyClass which have the same name but are in different namespaces and have  the same implementation but different access modifiers and then you can use preprocessor directives and choose the correct namespace to use in one line.